# Caching in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, caching

How should I set my Drupal web for better performance when I'm already satisfied with my theme and won't do many new theme adjustments?
The settings is probably in `admin/config/development/performance`

thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you don't anticipate important theme changes in the near future, you can well extend the cache expire time of your asset files like CSS and image files to multiple hours. You can do this via [Expire rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html) in .htaccess.

For optimal efficiency, I'd recommend installing a [Varnish](http://www.varnish-cache.org) proxy cache that accepts requests on port 80 and forwards them to Apache (running on another port, say 81). Varnish will then cache and deliver your asset files for multiple hours, thus reducing the load of the web server heavily. After installing and configuring Varnish and Apache, visit the performance page to also activate external caching of pages and set the page cache lifetime to a value you deem sensible.

We've seen huge improvements in page delivery time and server load by including Varnish in our Drupal hosting packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap out the default drupal caching mechanism for a memcached Implementation, also you could try using a nginx instead of an apache.

The perceived page load is also affected by the order in which the ressources on your page load. 
For example:
If the Browser loads a page, it starts from top to bottom.
CSS loads non blocking, which means that the browser does not have to wait while loading and executing the CSS. Javascript however is blocking, the browser has to load and execute every Javascript file one by one. Because of this it is recommended to put large javascript files which do not interact with the page before the onload Event is fired in the bottom of the page (right before the closing  tag).